# Why did my office add-in NPM fail to start? Can you check it for me please?

Tags: office365, office-js, add-in, webpack-dev-server, office-addins

My program is written step by step in accordance with official documents, and so is the command.Port 3000 is not used.
Why can't I start port 3000?

```
E:\My Office Add-in>npm start

> office-addin-taskpane-js@0.0.1 start E:\My Office Add-in
> office-addin-debugging start manifest.xml

Debugging is being started...
App type: desktop
Enabled debugging for add-in af71531f-d6c5-4ff3-854d-7b8dc52e3dcd. Debug method: 0
Starting the dev server... (webpack-dev-server --mode development)
Unable to start the dev server. Error: The dev server is not running on port 3000.
Sideloading the Office Add-in...
Debugging started.
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zq5mm.png)

Comment: Do you have something else running on that port? Alternatively, have you tried configuring the debugging to run on some other port?

Answer (score 1):

I had almost the exact same problem, and I fixed it using sudo:

`sudo npm start`